# Setting module page as home page in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

I have a module in which I created a custom page with controller and some logic. Works fine. I need that page to function as home page for my site. I found some topics about implementing IHomePageProvider, but that seems to be impossible because I can't find the definition of IHomePageProvider in the Orchard core. So I know there are some topics on this subject, but I didn't manage to find a solution that way, so therefore this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because it was removed at the same time as the routable part. This is now done using Alias.

Comment: Thanks. For others: you can enable Alias UI in your dashboard (modules). On the Alias management page you can quite easily set this up.

Comment: Maybe I spoke a bit too soon. I tried to setup the alias, but after entering the path to my custom page, Orchard saves Common/Error/NotFound?path=%2FHome%2FIndex instead. It seems to be unable to find the page, although it works fine when I request it myself. Any idea?

Comment: Well, that's how Autoroute does it: it just saves the alias as '/'.

Comment: Problem seemed to be one slash too many. I now set the alias "/" to route "DefaultIndex" (so WITHOUT a slash), and voila; it works!

Answer (score 1):

When working with Orchard Core (Orchard 2) there is setting with Home Route, which you can specify.

You can set it in your recipe.json file:

```
{
  "name": "settings",
  "HomeRoute": {
    "Action": "Index",
    "Controller": "ControllerName",
    "Area": "AreaName"
  }
}
```

or probablly later:

```
RouteValueDictionary newHomeRouteValue = ...;

var site = await _siteService.GetSiteSettingsAsync();
site.HomeRoute = newHomeRouteValue;
await _siteService.UpdateSiteSettingsAsync(site);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a home Route and Controller associated with this route. Take a look how it's accomplished in the CulturePicker module: [HomeRoutes](http://orchardculturepicker.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/e333c1fb3234#HomeRoutes.cs) and [LocalizableHomeController](http://orchardculturepicker.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/e333c1fb3234#Controllers/LocalizableHomeController.cs)